# function to sanitize input to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, sanitization

I am trying to put a general purpose function together that will sanitize input to a Mysql database. So far this is what I have:

```
function sanitize($input){
    if(get_magic_quotes_qpc($input)){

        $input = trim($input); // get rid of white space left and right
        $input = htmlentities($input); // convert symbols to html entities
        return $input;
    } else {

        $input = htmlentities($input); // convert symbols to html entities
        $input = addslashes($input); // server doesn't add slashes, so we will add them to escape ',",\,NULL
        $input = mysql_real_escape_string($input); // escapes \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a
        return $input;
    }
}
```

If i understood the definition of `get_magic_quotes_qpc()`. This is set by the php server to automatically escape characters instead of needing to use `addslashes()`.

Have I used `addslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` correctly together and is there anything else I could add to increase the sanitization.

Thanks

Comment: Combining as many escaping functions as possible is not a good approach. You'll just end up with triple escaped data, and can't use it for anything but in-html output.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

htmlentities() is unnecessary to make data safe for SQL.  It's used when echoing data values to HTML output, to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.  That's also an important security issue you need to be mindful of, but it's not related to SQL.

addslashes() is redundant with mysql_real_escape_string.  You'll end up with literal backslashes in your strings in the database.

Don't use magic quotes.  This feature has been deprecated for many years.  Don't deploy PHP code to an environment where magic quotes is enabled.  If it's enabled, turn it off.  If it's a hosted environment and they won't turn off magic quotes, get a new hosting provider.

Don't use `ext/mysql`.  It doesn't support query parameters, transactions, or OO usage.

Update: `ext/mysql` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 (2013-06-20), and removed in PHP 7.0.0 (2015-12-03). You really can't use it.

Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), and make your queries safer by using [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

For more details about writing safe SQL, read my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies).

Answer (score 6):

Magic quotes are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). Turn them off if you can :).

The second part `addslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_String` does pretty much the same (similar) thing. Just try

```
addslashes( '\\')
// and
mysql_real_escape_string( '\\')
```

Result should be `\\` so if you use

```
 mysql_real_escape_string( addslashes( '\\'))
```

you should get `\\` (or `'\\\\'` as string). Use only `mysql_real_escape_string` (better) OR `addslashes`, never both.

I recommend to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of raw functions and manual escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to apply htmlentities before saving data to the database? What if you want to use the data for something else than just writing it out to a browser? For example for searching, partitioning data, using the data in other programming languages, etc...

The only thing you really want to apply is mysql_real_escape_string (or use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)), nothing else.

I usually prefer to undo the effects of magic quotes entirely, always. Magic quotes is just cumbersome to work with and should never have been invented. Here's a snippet from the [PHP manual](http://se.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) to reverse the magic quotes:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the worst part that **adding slashes does not sanitize anything**, no matter what function was used.
and it should not be used in the means of whatever "sanitization" at all.

slashes do not "sanitize" data. Slashes do escape *string delimiters* only. Thus, the only sanitization you can talk of, is escaping **and and quoting**.

Otherwise, if you won't put quotes around "sanitized" string, you will have no protection at all.

Answer (score -5):

Use:

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

This will prevent bad data like DROP TABLE ;)

Comment: this is extremely incompentent answer. mysql_real_escape_string() does not "prevent bad data". Yet you cannot use this query injection with mysql extension anyway